# Magento 2 B2b feature

Tags: magento2

I installed Magento Enterprise 2.2.0 version but cannot install B2B extension following the [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions/b2b-installation.html)

I am getting the below error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package magento/extension-b2b. Check the package spelling, your version constr
  aint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

Is B2B really suported? And if yes how and where can I find information to install and use it.

Thank you.

Comment: do you get prompted to enter username and password?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't buy the extension on your account that you use in your `auth.json` file. Make sure this is present on the account and try again.

Comment: Buy? From where? Isn't it free and can be downloaded via composer and validated by magento access keys?

Comment: If it's free then add it to your account. You need to use your authentication keys from Magento Market Place account that has this module.

Comment: Can you provide the market place link for the extension,  as far as i could search there is no such link

Comment: Hymm... just make sure your credentials are correct in the auth.json file. Ask Magento Marekt Place customer support to confirm it. They extension must be somewhat connected to the market place as in step 2 it asks for authentication keys. 100% something wrong in auth.json file